# Blocking one user from disconnecting an active remote desktop session

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Some users share the same username in Windows Server. Few times, they need to access to the server at the same time. I would like to prevent one user from disconnecting an active remote desktop session. Is it possible to show a warning message to the second user like "You must wait that the active session closes"?

A solution could be to create a new user account, but it is not possible for a question of design of our license policy (not Windows, it is how we rent out application).

Answer (score 0):

With Group Policies, you can limit the amount of simultaneous connections: "Limit number of connections" and "Remove Disconnect option from Shut Down dialog" maybe "Set time limit for disconnected sessions" read more at http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc770884%28WS.10%29.aspx

That way you would make it impossible for users to Disconnect the session, keeping the license count small, and limit the number of simultaneous sessions anyway.